# Do I need to bake my pre-made pie crust?

Tags: baking, pie

The objective was to quickly put together a banoffee pie without going through making the pie crust. But this store bought Graham cracker pie crust comes with some confusing instructions a t the back.[This is the product with a picture](http://www.target.com/p/market-pantry-graham-cracker-crust-pie-crust-6-oz/-/A-13794232#?lnk=sc_qi_detailbutton). It says:

1. Ready to use.
2. For a golden crust, bake at 350 F for 5-7 minutes.

And then it goes on to outline some simple recipes for pies. What I understand from this is that there are two option, and I need to bake it only if I want the crust to develop a certain golden color. If I am strapped for time or any other reason I choose not to, I can use as is.

Is my interpretation correct or is it necessary that I bake it and let it cool before assembling my pie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pie crust is ready to use.  There is nothing in a graham cracker crust that *requires* baking, although a little toasting gives some color and deeper flavor.

If you are putting in a filling that will not be baked (a refrigerator pie), you might *choose* to "blind bake" (bake without filling) the crust for a few minutes to give it more color and flavor, but it is not required.

If your filling will require baking, there is little reason to bake the crust separately.